# How to attach an alert to audio, javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, time, settimeout, alert

How do I get the second audio to play on the second alert? I uploaded the website for an example of what I am trying to do. 3 seconds into the video, I am trying to make alerts appear. Which I've done. I just need to know how can I get the audio,'sorry.wav?.wav?.wav', to play on the second alert,'Is something here with me?'

I do not know javascript, at all, so please show me where a particular code goes into my current code, because simply I won't know.

Also this site is for an art assignment, so I appolgize if this is unethical, or odd, but this project requires attaching audio to alerts, or vice versa.

Current page example:

http://www.eves.website/second-original.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>eve_</title>
<link rel="icon" rel="preload" href="images/evecircle.png" />


<style>

#video {
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:-10px;



}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

</style>

<body onload="delayedAlert();">

<script>

var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 3000);
  then.getElementsByTagName('audiotwo')[0];
}

function slowAlert() {
 var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];



audio.play(); 
var myvar1;alert('Hello?')

audio.play(); 
var myvar2;alert('Is something here with me?');

}


</script>

 <audio>
  <source src="images/hellllloooo.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

 <audiotwo>
  <source src="images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audiotwo>




        <video autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" id="video" src="images/secondnew.mp4" width="1300px" height="auto" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1;" >
        Video not supported.
         </video>






</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<audiotwo>` is not valid HTML, call it `audio` as well, and make sure the `src` is well-formed:

```
<audio>
<source src="images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
</audio>
```

(is it really `images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav`? try fixing the filename)

Then select it via

```
const audio2 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];
```

and play it with

```
audio2.play();
```

(replace your second `audio.play();` just before `alert('Is something here with me?');` with `audio2.play();`)